# I need help re-installing any OS onto a Lenovo Yoga 6 laptop that probably has nothing on it's disk that can be recovered as well as a BIOS password

Tags: boot, lenovo-laptop, diskpart

So basically, the question is does anybody know of a way to recover or bypass a uefi password on a Lenovo yoga 6 (which doesn't have a cmos battery or switch to "jump" the bios as far as I know)? First I made it unbootable by encrypting the entire drive with veracrypt while secure boot and fast boot was still enabled, so I can't seem to get it to boot to anything else. I've gone to the boot manager during startup, and tried using CMD but I can't find a way to get it to recognize any rescue or installation media USBs. And I can't change the boot load order because it has a system password that I don't know. I have a usb that was the veracrypt rescue disk but I don't think it downloaded correctly because it's not bootable. but if i plug in drives and usbs it's recognized in diskpart. the entire drive was broken with the clean command during a moment of frustration. also, when I go to the boot options in the recovery environment it has the veracrypt bootloader there, it just doesn't work when I tell it to run. wut do?

Comment: No. New systems are secure. If you forgot / do not have the password, your computer is a nice paperweight.

Comment: Well take the drive out and wipe it first? (Assuming by unbootable you mean like the Windows Boot Manager is booted but fails to load the OS.)

Comment: If the drive also has a password, that will not work (in my experience) . Let’s hope there is no drive password.

Comment: @John Software *encryption* like veracrypt won't prevent you from wiping the drive, but yeah hardware *locking* mechanism like ATA password will. (Not familiar with TCG Opal.)

Comment: @TomYan The OP starts by mentioning "UEFI password" which is needed to access UEFI settings in order to change the boot order to the external installation media or any bootable rescue media for that matter. Indeed, it's exactly as John mentioned, *If you forgot / do not have the password, your computer is a nice paperweight*, it can't be reset even if had a jumper or similar. Even contacting customer support with proof of purchase the usual solution given is replace the mobo, something that most of the times is more expensive than a new machine.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Well, I am not familiar with how exactly one "veracrypt the whole drive" but I'm assuming UEFI here and that the ESP remains unencrypted (i.e. "whole drive" was really just "C:\"). In the case of UEFI, as long as the file the a boot entry refers to is found to be gone, often the firmware will simply invalidate/ignore or even remove it (especially when it comes to WBM), so unless USB booting is disabled instead of "unprioritized", wiping the drive and putting it back could actually allows you to boot from a USB installation medium and start afresh.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Besides, even if USB booting is disabled and/or it's the case of BIOS/legacy booting, you can really just put back a drive with installed (Linux) or "half-installed" (Windows) system. (By half-installed I mean like the state of just after the Windows Setup restart / dism-extraction + bcdboot.)

Comment: Does anybody happen to know how to change the amount of password attempts I can make? I'm pretty sure I would've used one of the shorter ones older ones I sometimes combine, I just have to figure out how exactly I entered it. Unless I find it hidden in some random place. I could've sworn I had decided not to even create one, but apparently I did, maybe on accident. And I thought veracrypt would've been like a whole disk encryption when using that "full system" option. So I couldn't replace the SSD with one that has a preinstalled OS?

Comment: `So I couldn't replace the SSD with one that has a preinstalled OS?` You can. The real *potential* problem with that is just if the OS is installed on some other computer, it might not be "portable" enough on various aspect. But as I said, the best shot for Windows is to put in a "half-installed" one. And unless you want to keep the data on the encrypted drive, you can simply use the same one after some partial zeroing out (wiping) at the beginning (of the drive, and well, of the process). Veracrypt does NOT "lock" the *drive itself*, but "encrypt" the *data*.

Comment: `it might not be "portable" enough on various aspect` If you are talking about Linux, the issues would be mainly whether or not the initramfs has included all the drivers required for real root mounting (for example, you prepared the installation on some computer with Intel RST turned on while this computer is on AHCI mode, or vice versa, and that you haven't made the default grub entry to boot with the "fallback" initramfs). Another issue could be your grub/shim (or veracrypt, idk) EFI executable is not placed at the fallback path but expects a "static" registration done on the UEFI (NVRAM).