# VM, dual book + VM, or multiple machines?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, liveusb, hardware-virtualization

I'm trying to configure my long term setup and have a menu of many devices, although most of them are older and have an issue or two.

> Lenovo ThinkCentre M82 SFF 
> w/ Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
> 16GB RAM
> Currently running Microsoft Windows 10 Pro | Version    10.0.19045 Build 19045
> {But originally had Windows 8.1 Pro}

I want this to be my main home/work-at-home machine, and after having days of trouble with the Intel HD Graphics driver on Windows 10 (had to turn virtualization off to disable memory integrity because it said "setting controlled by administrator") I've considered re-installing windows 8.1 pro because I've heard it argued that with a good AV suite it's better to use the native Windows OS for compatibility over upgrading to Win 10. I have many laptops, most are older than 6 years or so aside from a Lenovo Yoga 6 which I need to remember the admin password to flash bios after a mishap with veracrypt. If I figure that out or find a cheap board I'd probably just have that be my only laptop. It came with Windows 11 installed so I would likely keep that as the OS. I've been wanting to learn Kali Linux and have multiple Live USBs but I would like to have a device that either has it as the main OS or is available as a dual boot option. And there's possibility of playing with other distros but I'd likely use VMs or Live portables only. I also have a Surface Pro 4 running Win 11 pro and overall would like to only have one desktop, one laptop (maybe 2), and Surface tablet.

What config options would be best for what I'm looking for? I don't have a huge workflow at the moment, but I'm studying computer science and will likely be studying data science at some point or else pursuing entrepreneurial business and it would be nice to have my office established before trying to learn all of that.

My main question is if using the native OEM OS is better? And if it's worth it to keep an extra laptop instead of selling it so I can have one of the Linux or Windows OS installed on the hardware for performance? If I'm just learning Kali for fun would I get essentially the same quality from a VM or Live boot?

Comment: Windows 8.x is about to be ditched from official support, no point in keeping it and NO advantage whatsoever over Windows 10 (support at least until 2025); Windows 11 is out of the question for even somewhat old hardware. What you might have heard about AV either you misunderstood or it's pure nonsense.  Kali Linux is for a very specific purpose only. If you aren't pentesting Kali isn't for you and the way you learn Kali is by starting with a friendly and proper desktop Linux; after becoming proficient in regular Linux then, and only then, you may think about Kali.

Comment: Your question has lots of questions and mostly asks for opinions which is off-topic here. You should try to be more assertive and focused.

Comment: I used dual boot and dumped it many years ago: slow, inefficient and wasteful of many hours changing system. Long term:  Fast, large SSD and use Virtual Machines. I have been doing this since I dumped dual boot and have use VMware since version 1.

Comment: I use Kali in a VM.  Do not try to dual boot Kali with a modern Windows OS.  Up to the current version, it does not support UEFI or secure boot.

Comment: Thank you @ChanganAuto . Biggest reason for Kali was to attempt getting access to my Yoga 6 laptop with the lost admin password and also my old android phones (aside from a general interest in pentesting). So would you say I'd have better luck at trying to crack the laptop hash myself before trying to learn the programs on Kali? [https://superuser.com/questions/1764842/i-need-help-re-installing-any-os-onto-a-lenovo-yoga-6-laptop-that-probably-has-n?noredirect=1#comment2746329_1764842]

Comment: I would say you're better off reinstalling that laptop. And in any case everything that makes Kali Kali is available for any other Linux. The advantage of Kali is to have all the tools nicely packaged and that is at the same time its biggest disadvantage and the reason why it isn't a normal desktop Linux distro.