# Black screen of death after Windows 10 reinstallation

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, black-screen-of-death

So I just reinstalled Windows 10 using the 22h2 media installation creator downloaded from Microsoft. I've used this same download to reset windows before.

The machine is a ThinkCentre M82 and it had already been having issues with rebooting where it would come to an error that said something about not finding what it was looking for and I would have to force a hard shutdown and from there it would boot normally.

I ran the install media, chose 'install on this PC now' and to delete all files and applications. It worked, and I did the process of choosing the locale, keyboard layout etc, now when it boots it comes on, completes POST and gives the beep, and still nothing but a black screen. I've tried all the key combos I know, restarted, and checked hardware connections, but I'm stuck.

Comment: Do the installation media still boots normally as before, i.e., with the graphical user interface you'd expect?

Comment: Besides, *it had already been having issues with rebooting where it would come to an error that said something about not finding what it was looking for* suggests the drive was failing and likely failed for good now. If 1) you can boot the Windows installer as normal and 2) the target drive is correctly recognized then you can try to delete ALL partitions and install from that state.

Comment: To see if it's a drive issue, boot another OS from USB. If that works, then most likely, as @ChanganAuto stated, the drive is kaput.

Comment: You mentioned a beep during POST. Can you describe it (number, long, short) and the exact model of your computer.

Comment: @harrymc The model is mentioned in the question and supposedly is the same one mentioned in his other question with more detailed specs: https://superuser.com/q/1780362/653259

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes it's the same model from the previous question. And I've been able to get to BIOS now by pressing enter and pausing the boot-up. I tried moving the boot order but still nothing. The hard-drive is an SSD so I thought that was less likely to fail in that way? And the install media was run from the system drive (C). I have a Kali portable usb, macrium rescue usb, and kaperskys rescue usb so I'm thinking I'll try to get it to do the temporary boot to macrium first. Try to get to cmd so i can wipe and reinstall again?

Comment: @harrymc it's the usual 1 short beep which I think means it passed

Comment: Buy another SSD - Unplug existing SSD. Install W10 from USB not the local drive. Plugin old SSD and then recover data from old to new. See if system works as before. If not report back.

Comment: Agreed - one short beep is not a [ThinkCentre POST Beep symptom](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht505216-post-beep-symptoms-thinkcentre).

Answer (score 0):

Update, although it may not exactly be an answer, but I believe it was simply due to a dual monitor setup. It was plugged into a monitor and a tv, with the tv off and settings configured to only display on monitor previous to starting install. Confuses me why it would show the BSoD with the cursor on the monitor, but after unplugging the tv it booted back to the setup page for windows and has gone smooth from there. Sorry for the anticlimactic ending but thanks for the help.

Sorry if this shouldn't be included, but would anybody say that it's worth it to do it again correctly by wiping the drive and installing from USB? I only did this to begin with because it was messy with leftovers from previous users and my habit of installing too much software- no viruses or severe performance issues. Feel free to message me any opinions or requests for more details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).